# Formatting JSON for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to wrangle some data to make a recommender system for an app. Of course, to do this I need a record of which users like which posts. I currently have that data in a JSON file that is formatted like this (numbers being post id, and letters being user ids):

```
    {
       "-1234": {
         "abc": "abc",
         "def": "def",
         "ghi": "ghi"
    },
       "-5678": {
         "jkl": "jkl",
         "mno": "mno"
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get this into a pandas dataframe that would look like this:

[example format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEUog.png)

I've tried using a few online JSON to CSV converters out of laziness which unsurprisingly didn't bring it into a useable format for me. I've tried using "print(json_normalize(data))", as well which also did not work, and put each instance of a like into separate columns.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the desired output format of the dataframe? What are the columns names? Are the keys and values in your structure always identical? Please show the exact desired output for the example you provide.

Comment: @Cleb edited the original post to include format! Yes, the keys and values are always identical for some reason, not sure why the database was set up that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution optimized for the peculiarities in your dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
       "-1234": {
         "abc": "abc",
         "def": "def",
         "ghi": "ghi"
    },
       "-5678": {
         "jkl": "jkl",
         "mno": "mno"
    }}
formatted = [{'PostID': d, 'User Like': list(data[d].keys())} for d in data]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(formatted)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience for such simple formats, writing a quick and dirty loop is usually the fastest method rather than finding some ready solution and customizing it. An example for the data you gave here:

```py
import json
my_json="""    {
       "-1234": {
         "abc": "abc",
         "def": "def",
         "ghi": "ghi"
    },
       "-5678": {
         "jkl": "jkl",
         "mno": "mno"
    }
    }"""
parsed_json = json.loads(my_json)
print(parsed_json)
# result:
# {'-1234': {'abc': 'abc', 'def': 'def', 'ghi': 'ghi'},
# '-5678': {'jkl': 'jkl', 'mno': 'mno'}}

for key in parsed_json.keys():
    line = ''
    line += key
    line += ' | '
    for value in parsed_json[key].values():
        line += value + ', '
    line = line[:-2] # stripping the ', ' from the end of the line
    print(line)
# result:
# -1234 | abc, def, ghi
# -5678 | jkl, mno
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

Thanks Zaroth

```
import json
my_json="""    {
       "-1234": {
         "abc": "abc",
         "def": "def",
         "ghi": "ghi"
    },
       "-5678": {
         "jkl": "jkl",
         "mno": "mno"
    }
    }"""
parsed_json = json.loads(my_json)
```

---

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(k, [*v]) for k, v in parsed_json.items()],
    columns=['PostID', 'User Like']
)

  PostID        User Like
0  -1234  [abc, def, ghi]
1  -5678       [jkl, mno]
```

#### OR

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'PostID': [*parsed_json],
    'User Like': [[*v] for v in parsed_json.values()]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"-1234": {"abc": "abc","def": "def","ghi": "ghi"},"-5678": {"jkl": "jkl","mno": "mno"}}

key = []
val = []

for k,v in data.items():
    key.append(k)
    val.append(list(v.values()))

pd.DataFrame(zip(key,val),columns=['PostID','User Like'])
```

Comment: Adding some commentary about how and why your code actually solves the problem helps both the asker and other people arriving here understand your answer...